Как образовать прилагательное от топонима, оканчивающегося на Е?
Скажите, пожалуйста, как и по какому правилу можно образовать прилагательное от существительного-топонима, оканчивающегося на Е? Например, есть в Турции город Эдирне. Какое получится прилагательное? Эдирнейский? Эдирнеский?..

• Есть такое мнение "Грамоты":

В письменных источниках встречается прилагательное в двух графических вариантах: эдирненский, эдирнинский.

Я бы провела аналогию с такими известными городами (и соответственно — с прилагательными): Туапсе — туапсинский, Душанбе — душанбинский.
Городов, заканчивающихся на -не, не так уж и много.
Можно посмотреть: Города, заканчивающиеся на буквы НЕ (есть здесь и Эдирне).
Из них самые известные мне — это Закопане (закопанский) и Резекне (резекненский).
Думаю, что в каждом конкретном случае выбор делается по принципу благозвучия.

Эдирненский или эдирнинский, и точнее Вам никто не ответит.


